# How to fix this logical error in the following code?

Tags: c++, file-io

When I store the username in a file along with the password appending it to be a single array, the Name which I do not store in the file comes along with it.

This code is in Borland C++.

```
void new_user()

{

    clrscr();

    cout<<"\nEnter your name: ";
    gets(name);

    cout<<"\nEnter your phone number: ";
    gets(phone);

    cout<<"\nEnter your email: ";
    gets(email);

    cout<<"\nEnter your address: ";
    cout<<"\nHouse no. and Area: ";
    gets(area);
    cout<<"\nCity: ";
    gets(city);
    cout<<"\nState: ";
    gets(state);
    cout<<"\nEnter the pincode: ";
    cin>>pincode;
    getch();
    int x=1;
    while(x==1)
    x=createuser();

}


int createuser()

{

            char username[20];
    int c=0;
    ofstream fout,f;
    ifstream fin;
    cout<<"\nCreate a username (max. 10 letters): ";
    fout.open("usern.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
    gets(uname);
    fout<<uname;
    fout.close();

    fin.open("usern.txt",ios::in|ios::beg);

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin>>username;
        if(strcmp(username,uname)==0)
        c++;

    }

    fin.close();
    fout.open("usern.txt",ios::app);
    if(c>1)
    {
        cout<<"\nUsername already exists!";
        return (1);
    }


    else
    {

        cout<<"\nCreate a password (max. 10 letters): ";

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            password[i]=getch();
            cout<<"*";
        }
        fout<<password<<'\n';
        cout<<"\nUser registered successfully!";
        cout<<"\nThank you for signing up to Hindustan Tours and Travels";
        f.close();

        return(2);
 }
```

When I enter the username as 'iniyan2003' and password as 'iniyan0307', the expected file data should be 'iniyan2003iniyan0307'. Instead it is 'iniyan2003iniyan0307Iniyan'.

Comment: Fix a logical issue by create a GUI application because `clrscr` is not portable across platforms and many terminal (console) emulators don't support it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        password[i]=getch();
        cout<<"*";
    }
    fout<<password<<'\n';
```

You read 10 characters with `getch` and so you have an array of ten characters. But then you treat it as if it was a *string*, which it's not. There is no way for that last line to know that it should write ten characters, so it writes more than that.

Strings are a specific thing in C and are not the same as arrays of characters. Do not use string functions (like `strcmp` or `operator<<(const char *)`) unless you pass them actual C-style strings. In fact, since you're coding in C++, don't use C-style strings at all. Use `std::string` and use things like `if (a=="hello")` instead of `if ((strcmp(a, "hello")==0)` and make your life easier.

There are a lot of other issues with this code. One other that I'll point out:

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    fin>>username;
    if(strcmp(username,uname)==0)
    c++;

}
```

You don't check if the read succeeds, you just assume it does. It seems you are expecting the `eof()` function to predict whether or not a future read will succeed. That's not what it does, it only tells you about the past and is not a substitute for checking if a read succeeded.